# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I'm unfortunately getting a horizontal scrollbar when the page is collapsed on smaller screens. I've tried adding rows. Removing containers. Double checking. I can't figure it out.

I made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kGJuSkNitK) with the code. Like I said I've added and removed from the page structure and it has yet to go away so I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Just to clarify I've got through many of the previous questions on this topic and tried those solutions and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the navbar-nav inside the navbar-header causes an overflow due to padding. Just a use `navbar-text` link instead.

http://www.bootply.com/zw2H1wW2EJ

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a href="tel:555-555-5555" class="visible-xs navbar-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> Tap To Give Us A Call</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried `navbar-text` it removed some styles I was using so instead I created a new class I added to it called `navbar-no-margin` which has the properties of `margin-left: 0!important;` and `margin-right: 0!important;` which retained the styles but fixed the problem. Thank you.